# Mergesort or Database?

Tags: java, performance, comparison, mergesort

I have a rather complex database-query which gives me 30 million records - roughly 15 times the amount of data which would fit into memory. I need to access all records from the database sequentially (i.e. sorted). For performance reasons it is not possible to use an "order by" statement as the preparation of the ordered `ResultSet` uses roughly 40 minutes.

I see two possible options to solve my problem:

1. Dump the resulting data into an unordered file and use some form of merge-sort to arrive with a sorted file
2. Flatten data and dump it into a secondary database and reselect it using ordering mechanisms of the database.

Which would you prefer for reasons of elegance and performance?

If your choice is number two, do you have a suggestion for the database to use? Would you prefer SQLite, MySQL or Apache Derby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sorting large amounts of data, one solution is to sort them into blocks of data you can load. e.g a 30th (15 * 2) and sort those records.  This will give you 30 sorted files.

Take the 30 sorted files and do a merge sort between them. (This requires at least 30 records in memory) You can process them as you sort them.

BTW: Its is also possible its time to buy a more powerful computer.  You can buy a PC with 16 GB of memory and an SSD for close to $1000. For $2000 you can get a fast PC with 32 GB of memory. This could save you a lot of time. ;)

Comment: I'm aware how merge-sort works (and even related sort algorithms trying to make use of the memory available), I am, however looking for the answer to the question which is faster/more elegant, merge sort or database sort. I'm also aware that whichever implementation I choose, my working time will be more expensive than a better PC, however, my company is still on 32bit Windows and I've already maxed out the 1.5 GB memory available to the 32bit-JVM.

Comment: The most elegant solution is to use the right tool for the job. ;) Given your restrictions, I would say you should go with what works. AFAIK the generally accepted solution, in this situation, is a merge sort.  Personally I would continue to use your standard system for email and word, but not for this type of problem.

Comment: Do you know of any situation where solution 2 has been considered and rejected or accepted for whatever reasons? Is there a reason why you reject the solution or is it merely because it is the more unconventional solution? From my point of view, mergesort involves one additional read/write cycle and although I assume sequentially writing a file is much faster than inserting the same amount of data into a database, the question is, is it so much faster? Unfortunately I cannot compare the solutions - I have a budget to implement one, not both.

Comment: Solution 2 will be dramatically slower and possibly more complicated than using plain files. Its a pretty convensional one to use but only when a small fraction of the data is being added or selected at a time.  If you are adding larger portions or all the data, it will be so much slower as to be avoided.

Comment: Your budget must be incredibly restrictive.  You should be able to implement either solution in a day with no additional hardware (unless your hardware is worse than I thought)  I would go back to the person asking you to do this and check they seriously want you to do this if they won't give you the resources to do it.  You should make them aware that you don't have the resources to explore all reasonable options and if it doesn't work, at least you warned them this is dangerous strategy and it could fail.

Comment: Again, the budget is not the topic here, it is the company policy which sticks all clients to Windows XP 32 bit unless the BigUpgrade(TM) is coming on later this year - which will be too late for this tool anyway. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

For the best performance, definitely option 1.  Dumping the data to a flat file, sorting with a good external sort program, and then reading back in will use the minimum amount of resource from all the options. If you want to post specifics on the record length and system configuration (memory, disk speeds) I can let you know how long it should take.

The problem with option 2 is that it may simply reproduce the problem you currently have in another form.  I can't tell from your post how complex your query is (how many tables you're joining), and it may be that a lot of your 40 minutes is being spent in the join.  But even if that is the case, option 2 still has to do an external sort if your data is 15 times the size of available memory.  The only databases that do this well are those that are designed to use a commercial external sort under the covers, so you're back to option 1 anyway.

As far as elegance is concerned, that's often in the eye of the beholder ;-).  Personally, I find ultra-high performance elegant in its own right, but it's kinda subjective.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say which method will be better for you.  You really have to benchmark it.
A good idea is to increase your memory and keep an ordered index there. Then retrieve the data from disk/database (based on index of the item that you need)